# Printing without newline (print 'a',) prints a space, how to remove?

Tags: python, string, printing, python-2.x

I have this code:

```
>>> for i in xrange(20):
...     print 'a',
... 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
```

I want to output `'a'`, without `' '` like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm surprised that no-one's yet mentioned `"".join("a" for i in xrange(20))`. (It's much more flexible than just doing `"a" * 20`, as I assume it's a simplfied example).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

There are a number of ways of achieving your result. If you're just wanting a solution for your case, use [string multiplication](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) as [@Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/print-python-whithout-n/4499087#4499087) mentions. This is only going to work if each of your `print` statements prints the same string. Note that it works for multiplication of any length string (e.g. `'foo' * 20` works).

```
>>> print 'a' * 20
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

If you want to do this in general, build up a string and then print it once. This will consume a bit of memory for the string, but only make a single call to `print`. Note that string concatenation using `+=` is now linear in the size of the string you're concatenating so this will be fast.

```
>>> for i in xrange(20):
...     s += 'a'
... 
>>> print s
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Or you can do it more directly using [sys.stdout](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout).[write()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write), which `print` is a wrapper around. This will write only the raw string you give it, without any formatting. Note that no newline is printed even at the end of the 20 `a`s.

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in xrange(20):
...     sys.stdout.write('a')
... 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>>>
```

Python 3 changes the `print` statement into a [print() function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print), which allows you to set an `end` parameter. You can use it in >=2.6 by importing from `__future__`. I'd avoid this in any serious 2.x code though, as it will be a little confusing for those who have never used 3.x. However, it should give you a taste of some of the goodness 3.x brings.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> for i in xrange(20):
...     print('a', end='')
... 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>>>
```

Comment: @A A I read the question when the string multiplication answer was present, and thought I'd give an overview of several options. The others came while I was putting together my answer. It was accepted soon after, otherwise I would've likely deleted it.

Comment: -1 Don't build up strings by concatenation; it's O(n^2) instead of O(n). Use `"".join(...)` instead.

Comment: I have no problem with your answer, it summarizes everything and that's good. But by doing this, you discourage other people who answer. There are many good answers and all deserve +1. Just imagine if everyone started making summaries.

Comment: @katrielalex: Does it matter? Has the OP asked for optimization or complexity? And will it matter for 20 strings? Come on, you seriously must be joking.

Comment: @katrielalex Wrong, string concatenation using `+=` in Python is a constant time operation for concatenation of a single character.

Comment: I've started a discussion about this on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72893/acceptable-to-group-together-many-answers-into-a-new-one-explaining-when-each-is)

Answer (score 119):

From [PEP 3105: print As a Function](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3105-print-as-a-function) in the [What’s New in Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#what-s-new-in-python-2-6) document:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('a', end='')
```

Obviously that only works with python 3.0 or higher (or 2.6+ with a `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning). The `print` statement was  removed and became the `print()` function by default in Python 3.0.

Answer (score 41):

You can suppress the space by printing an empty string to stdout between the `print` statements.

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in range(20):
...   print 'a',
...   sys.stdout.write('')
... 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

However, a cleaner solution is to first build the entire string you'd like to print and then output it with a single `print` statement.

Comment: @Soulseekah: Yes, using only `sys.stdout.write()` is more convenient in this case. However, I wanted to show that writing an empty string to stdout suppresses the space between elements written using `print`, which could be useful in similar situations.

Answer (score 34):

You could print a backspace character (`'\b'`):

```
for i in xrange(20):
    print '\ba',
```

result:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 30):

Python 3.x:

```
for i in range(20):
    print('a', end='')
```

Python 2.6 or 2.7:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in xrange(20):
    print('a', end='')
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want them to show up one at a time, you can do this:

```
import time
import sys
for i in range(20):
    sys.stdout.write('a')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

`sys.stdout.flush()` is necessary to force the character to be written each time the loop is run.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a side note:

Printing is O(1) but building a string and then printing is O(n), where n is the total number of characters in the string. So yes, while building the string is "cleaner", it's not the most efficient method of doing so.

The way I would do it is as follows:

```
from sys import stdout
printf = stdout.write
```

Now you have a "print function" that prints out any string you give it without returning the new line character each time.

```
printf("Hello,")
printf("World!")
```

The output will be: Hello, World!

However, if you want to print integers, floats, or other non-string values, you'll have to convert them to a string with the str() function.

```
printf(str(2) + " " + str(4))
```

The output will be: 2 4

Comment: Do you say that I can output an infinite amount of text in same time as outputting one character?

Comment: When I redefined printf to stdout.write, my stdout.write seems to be printing the number of chartacters the string is: "Hello,6"
What gives? What's going on? And how do I stop it?

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by O(1) O(n)? I don't understand what that refers to

Comment: @Tom It's referring to complexity (Big O notation) as a reflection of the _cost_ of the operation. O(1) is constant time - _ideal_ - and O(n) is linear time - _okay_ but way too expensive for something so simple.
Although, for small things, the time you spend using your brain to worry about these things is more computationally wasteful than just using string concatenation.

Answer (score 6):

without what?
do you mean

```
>>> print 'a' * 20
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

?

Answer (score 6):

Either what [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465159/ant) [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/print-python-whithout-n/4499087#4499087), or accumulate into a string, then print once:

```
s = '';
for i in xrange(20):
    s += 'a'
print s
```

Answer (score 3):

this is really simple

for python 3+ versions you only have to write the following codes

```
for i in range(20):
      print('a',end='')
```

just convert the loop to the following codes, you don't have to worry about other things

Answer (score 2):

**WOW!!!**

It's pretty **long time** ago

Now, In **python 3.x** it will be pretty easy

code:

```
for i in range(20):
      print('a',end='') # here end variable will clarify what you want in 
                        # end of the code
```

output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

**More about print() function**

```
print(value1,value2,value3,sep='-',end='\n',file=sys.stdout,flush=False)
```

**Here**:

```
value1,value2,value3
```

you can print **multiple values** using **commas**

```
sep = '-'
```

3 values will be separated by '-' character

you can use any character instead of that even string like sep='@' or sep='good'

```
end='\n'
```

by default print function put '\n' charater at the end of output

but you can use any character or string by changing end variale value

like end='$' or end='.' or end='Hello'

```
file=sys.stdout
```

this is a default value, system standard output

using this argument you can create a **output file stream** like

```
print("I am a Programmer", file=open("output.txt", "w"))
```

by this code you will create a file named **output.txt** where your output
**I am a Programmer** will be stored

```
flush = False
```

It's a default value 
using **flush=True** you can forcibly **flush the stream**

Answer (score 2):

as simple as that

```
def printSleeping():
     sleep = "I'm sleeping"
     v = ""
     for i in sleep:
         v += i
         system('cls')
         print v
         time.sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 0):

in python 2, add (,) after print and it will act as end='' in python 3. But for space in between, you are still off to use **future** version of the print.

```
for x in ['a','b','c','d']:
   print(x),
```