# Fibonacci series printing horizontally

Tags: python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing without newline (print 'a',) prints a space, how to remove?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove)

I need to print the Fibonacci series Horizontally..ie., the output must be like this 
The Fibonacci series is : 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13.
I don't want to print it as a list also.
I know how to print in vertically.. But can't print it horizontally with 'The Fibonacci series is : ' only coming once.. Please help guys!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want all the numbers in the series to be printed on the same line.

Your code would look like this

```
print 'The Fibonacci series is : ',
for i in xrange(1,10):
    #Calculate the next number 'n' to print
    print n,
```

Answer (score -1):

Working solution based on Rajesh answer.

```
a,b = 0,1
limit = 40
print 'The Fibonacci series is :', str(a), #str() necessary since 'print 0,' == ''
while(b < limit):
    print b,
    a,b = b,a+b

# output:
# The Fibonacci series is :  0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34
```