# Practical difference between keyword "print" and function "print" in Python

Tags: python

For Python2x If we use,

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

the `print` will become function which is previously the `keyword`

But practically,

How two of these are different ?

I can still use `print` the same way as I was using it when it was a `keyword`, then what difference does it make and how could it be more efficient than before ?

Comment: It's not a question of efficiency.

Comment: [PEP-3105 : Make print a function](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you can read some [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) with examples and [PEP3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) with more details.

As quick differences, there are several things which are very easy to do with print function (Python 3 or `from __future__ import print_function`) or at least very consistently:

**No newline**

```
print('Hello!', end='')
```

That was more complicated [in python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove).

**Print to stderr**

```
import sys
print('ERROR!!!!!', file=sys.stderr)
```

[In python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5574737/1970845).

Answer (score 7):

Not really.  With the function you must do `print(stuff)`, but with the statement you can do `print stuff`.

The main advantage is that, if `print` is a function, you can assign a different function to that name.  For instance, you could create a new function that not only outputs the data to the screen but also logs it to a file.  If you assign this function to the builtin `print`, then any code that uses `print` will automatically log to a file.  This is not possible with `print` as a statement, and you must resort to other techniques to get the same effect.

There are also some smaller changes associated with the way `print` formats its output.  The statement used "magic" syntax (e.g., a trailing comma suppressed a following space), while the function uses standard keyword-argument conventions.

Also, `print` is always a function in Python 3.  It's in Python 2 that you must use the `__future__` import if you want `print` as a function.

Comment: but that doesn't make it any better ? now, does it ?

Comment: Always remember that "better" is relative.  Just because a software feature doesn't appear to directly benefit your projects doesn't mean that it brings no benefits to (possibly thousands of) others.  What works for one doesn't necessarily work for others and vice-versa.