# Printing on the same line with time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print two strings on the same line using a timer in between. Here's the code:

```
import time

print "hello",
time.sleep(2)
print "world"
```

But it seems the program waits for two seconds then prints both strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing without newline (print 'a',) prints a space, how to remove?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove)

Comment: That works fine for me, waiting between the two words. You could trying flushing `stdout` in-between (`import sys; sys.stdout.flush()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in python 2.7 you could use the print_function from the **future** package

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep

print("hello, ", end="")
sleep(2)
print("world!")
```

But like you said, this waits 2 seconds then prints both strings. In light of Gui Rava's answer you can flush stdout, here is a sample which should get you in the right direction:

```
import time
import sys

def _print(string):
    sys.stdout.write(string)
    sys.stdout.flush()

_print('hello ')
time.sleep(2)
_print('world')
```

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that , by default, the console output is buffered.
Since Python 3.3 `print()` supports the keyword argument `flush` ([see documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)):

```
print('hello', flush=True)
```

If you use an prior versionf of python, you can force a flush like this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```