# Program in Python for alphabets in pattern

Tags: python

I have written this program:

```
for i  in range(1,6):
    for j in range(65,65+i):
        a =  chr(j)
        print (a)
    print
```

I want to print a pattern as follows:

```
A
A B
A B C
A B C D
A B C D E
```

but i am not getting the desired output

i am getting

```
A

A
B

A
B
C

A
B
C
D

A
B
C
D
E
```

Comment: Did you try with `print a,`? The comma makes the output on the same line.

Comment: Yes i got it i had to use comma after print a,

Answer (score 5):

In python 2, simply put a comma after the print statement:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in range(65, 65+i):
        a = chr(j)
        print a,
    print
```

For python 3, or in python 2 using `from __future__ import print_function` you would do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in range(65, 65+i):
        a = chr(j)
        print(a, end=" ")
    print()
```

Note that I put a space (`" "`) as the end character. You could set it to `""` and the output will be without spaces, like so:

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
```

Comment: with `from __future__ import print_function` the Python 3 version, will also work in Python 2.6 and newer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `str.join` using `string.ascii_uppercase`:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(" ".join(ascii_uppercase[:i]))
```

Or using your range logic:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(" ".join(chr(j) for j in range(65, 65 + i)))
```

Comment: I was just typing this answer, mostly because constructing the string A-E and printing it in one go is much faster than calling print 6 times to print each letter individually and a newline.

Answer (score 1):

`print a` (or `print (a)`) will print a newline. If you want to suppress the newline you can write

```
print a,
```

For more infos see the question: [Printing without newline (print 'a',) prints a space, how to remove?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove)

Comment: There is also a nice SO answer which differentiates by the different Python versions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/5682996)

Answer (score 0):

- Just put a comma after print(a) in python 3.
- In python 2 you just put    end=" " inside of print(a,end=" ")

  ```
  #!usr/bin/env python
  for i  in range(1,6):
      for j in range(65,65+i):
          a =  chr(j)
          print (a),
          print
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(" ")
    for j in range(65,65+i):
        a=chr(j)
        print(a,end=" ")
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not using end=" " in print statement, it is required to use end=" " because python print() function by default print in new line, thats why at every iteration it is jumping into new line. Correction to your code is:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(" ")
    for j in range(65,65+i):
        print(chr(j),end=" ")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i  in range(1,6):
for j in range(65,65+i):
    a =  chr(j)
    print (a, end = " ")
print()
```

Here, the modification is in the first print statement where I just have added the end parameter.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i  in range(1,6):
    for j in range(65,65+i):
        a =  chr(j)
        print (a)
        print("")
```

output:

```
C

A                                                                                                                               

B                                                                                                                               

C                                                                                                                               

D                                                                                                                               

A                                                                                                                               

B                                                                                                                               

C                                                                                                                               

D                                                                                                                               

E
```